# Подсчёт сообщений в файл

Tags: файлы, php

Здравствуйте, помогите с подсчётом сообщений. План: пользователь добавляет сообщение, оно записывается в файл и выводится, а также в др. файл нужно записать количество сообщений. Один раз => 1, второе добавил - 2. Вот так я добавляю запись:

```
if (@$_POST['submit']) {
    $letters = letters . dat;
    header("location:index.php");
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $message = htmlspecialchars($message);
    $message = ereg_replace("\n", "<br>", $message);
    $fh      = fopen($letters, "a");
    $str     = $mylogin . ":::" . $myphoto . ":::" . $message . ":::" . date('H:m') . "\r\n";
    fputs($fh, $str);
    fclose($fh);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

добавьте в Ваш код еще пару строчек (*после закрытия файла с сообщениями*):

1. Открытие файла с количеством сообщений
2. Считывание строки файла в переменную
3. Увеличивайте переменную на 1
4. Перезаписываете в файл с количеством эту переменную
5. Закрываете файл с количеством сообщений